# PHP function in Include file and call via main file include in bottom

Tags: function, include, call

```
main.php

$x = 75;
$y = 25;

addition();
echo $z;

//include file in bottom of main page

      include 'include_call.php';
```

```
Second Page - include_call.php

     function addition() {
      $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
     }
```

My Question is :
include file in main page at bottom then function not working and page shows error
my question is can we can't call function in include file at bottom of main page
and same working fine if we include file at top of main page

Comment: PHP scripts are executed from top to bottom. At the time it reaches the addition() call in your main.php file, the second file has not been included yet, so the function does not exist, which results in the error you see. Including the file with the function at any time before the function call should work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.